# Runtime Issues on 144Hz Monitors

Tags: unity

I've recently finished my first ever Unity game. The game runs okay in my end but two of my friends had issues with the game. They both have 144hz monitors and the issues are solved when they lower the refresh rate to 60Hz. The problems are that any object who has a velocity depending on Time.deltatime, it gets halved. Is there a way to fix this on code so that nobody has to reduce their refresh rate when playing?

Here is an example code of a snowball projectile's behaviour. The snowball usually stays alive for `3f` seconds and that allows him to go across the whole screen but in 144hz runtime, the snowball goes really slow and it does not last enough to even get across the half of the screen.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Snowball : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 20f;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject impactEffect;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        Destroy(gameObject, 3f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime * 75;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        if(hitInfo.CompareTag("Player") || hitInfo.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Instantiate(impactEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my game if anyone is interested in further examination: [itch.io link](https://ereneren.itch.io/snowball-street)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to adjust `rigidbody.velocity` by `Time.deltaTime`, because it is already defined in units per second. The Unity physics engine will take care of taking deltaTime (or rather fixedDeltaTime) into account when applying the velocity to the position.